# get response headers post request python

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape Jaap.nl, however I have some difficulty. When you want to search your city for instance Amsterdam it redirects you to a url with more than only Amsterdam.

base_url : https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/ >
https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam

I want to capture the extra bit (noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam). I see there is a Post request to get the extended url in the headers as location before redirecting a get to that page, but I cannot capture that piece in my code. See code below:

```
def post_page(type="koophuizen", city="amsterdam"):
    url = f"https://www.jaap.nl/{type}"
    headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0",
               "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
    payload = {"action": "searchExtensive",
               "url": f"/{type}",
               "search_input_extensive": city}
    response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    print(response.headers)
post_page()
```

I get this response:

```
    {'Cache-Control': 'private', 
     'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 
     'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 
     'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 
     'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/8.5', 
     'Set-Cookie': 'SESSIONToken=7f8c65d3-7962-41a8-9604-a996957fd0ad; expires=Tue, 20-Nov-2029 23:11:36 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly, lastcity=76; path=/', 
     'X-AspNetMvc-Version': '4.0', 
     'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 
     'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET, ARR/3.0, ASP.NET', 
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains', 
     'X-Handled-By': 'TORNADO', 
     'X-Jaap-Router': 'Routed', 
     'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 
     'Date': 'Wed, 20 Nov 2019 23:11:36 GMT', 
     'Content-Length': '32956'}
```

While I'm looking for:

```
    "Location": "/koophuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam"
```

As I can see when I'm inspecting the post request response headers in the browser

I constantly get 200 as response code, while I'm looking for 302 even with allow_redirects=False and using Session to save the cookies I can't get it working.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
import requests

city_to_search=str(input("Insert your city"))

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:71.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/71.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Origin': 'https://www.jaap.nl',
    'DNT': '1',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Referer': 'https://www.jaap.nl/koophuizen/',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
}

data = {
  'action': 'searchExtensive',
  'url': '/koophuizen',
  'search_input_extensive': city_to_search
}

response = requests.post('https://www.jaap.nl/', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Comment: You were right! Something in my headers was not correct. When I copied your code it worked indeed, thanks!